# How to use res.redirect in a webtask?

Tags: webtask

I'm exporting an express app called `eggman` with `webtask-tools`.

My `res.redirect('/walrus')`ses don't work.

The url for my app is `….sandbox.auth0-extend.com/eggman/walrus`, which means `/` will point to `….sandbox.auth0-extend.com/walrus` instead of `/eggman/walrus`.

Is there an elegant way to set a basepath to all redirects?

Answer (score 1):

The hack is to use `res.redirect('/<webtaskName>/path'`.

I've sent a [PR](https://github.com/auth0/webtask-tools/pull/30) to address this at the library level but I don't expect them to implement it.